# Find the first two nonzero digits of float number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I want to get the first two nonzero digits of a float number using math library.
for example for

```
x = 1.27
```

the answer would be

```
12
```

and for

```
x = 0.025
```

the answer would be

```
25
```

I could find the first and second nonzero number:

```
a = str(x)
o1 = int(a.replace('0', '')[1])
o2 = int(a.replace('0', '')[2])
```

and then I can concat them but I get

> string index out of range

error for big numbers.

Comment: What about the number 0.101? Is the output 10 or 11?

Comment: At least some downvotes were *before* you posted any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
from itertools import islice

def first_n_nonzero_digits(l, n):
    return ''.join(islice((i for i in str(l) if i not in {'0', '.'}), n))

first_n_nonzero_digits(1.27, 2)
# '12'

first_n_nonzero_digits(0.025, 2)
# '25'
```

---

Here's one without any imports and using `sorted`:

```
def first_n_nonzero_digits_v2(l, n):
    return ''.join(sorted(str(x), key=lambda x: x in {'0', '.'}))[:2]

first_n_nonzero_digits_v2(1.27, 2)
# '12'

first_n_nonzero_digits_v2(0.025, 2)
# '25'
```

Comment: I don't want to use any library except math library.

Comment: Check using sorted @freesoul

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
str(x).replace(".","").replace("0", "")[:2]
```

Comment: Fails for instance with 1.02

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def nonzeroDigits(f,n=2):
    counter = 1
    s = str(f).replace(".","")
    for ndx,i in enumerate(s):
        if i == "0":
            counter = 1
            continue
        if counter >= n:
            return s[ndx - n + 1: ndx + 1]
        counter += 1
    raise ValueError("Doesn't have non-zero consecutive Digits")
```

I have tired to make it as simple as possible without using any third-party library.

```
print(nonzeroDigits(1.27))
# print(nonzeroDigits(1.02)) # Raise ValueError Exception
print(nonzeroDigits(0.025))
```

Returns:

```
12
25
```